# how to replace getInitialProps with getStaticProps for seo handling and also for props

Tags: reactjs, next.js, seo

- Im trying to replace [getInitialPropss()](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-static-props) with [getStaticProps()](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/get-initial-props), but im unable to do it, we can only use 1 function in one file
- Also by using getStaticProps both SEO handling and normal props should work

index.tsx

```
const homePage: NextPage = () => {
    return (
        <>
            //jsx code
        </>
    );
};

homePage.getInitialProps = async () => ({
    pageProps: {
        pageName:
            "abc",
        pageDescription: dataPageDescription.home,
        pageClassName: "home",
        mobileHeaderTitle: MobileMenuPageTitleEnum.home
    }
});

// export const getStaticProps = async () => {
//     const pageProps = {
//         pageName:
//             "abc",
//         pageDescription: dataPageDescription.home,
//         pageClassName: "home",
//         mobileHeaderTitle: MobileMenuPageTitleEnum.home
//     };
//     const data = await request(homePage);
//     return { props: { data, pageProps } };
// };

export default homePage;
```

_app.tsx

```
function Website({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    const currentProps = {
        ...pageProps
    };
//rest code
```

how can I replace getInitialProps() with getStaticProps()?

Any advice would be helpful..

Answer (score 0):

`getInitialProps` will work just fine for your use case. According to [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/get-initial-props)

> For the initial page load, getInitialProps will run on the server only. getInitialProps will then also run on the client when navigating to a different route with the next/link component or by using next/router.

If a crawler visits your page `getInitialProps` will run on the server, returning the SSR page. The same applies to visitors opening the site via direct links (search results, shared links, etc.).

But if you use [Link](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/link) from Next.js, it will navigate to that page via the client side (no page reload) and data will be fetched using the client (will run in the browser, not Next.js server)